# How to rotate a image and save in folder in php?

Tags: php

I want to rotate a image and save it to the folder using php. How can I achieve that?

The code I have tried so far

```
$filename = 'pexels-philip-justin-mamelic-2872667.jpg';
$degrees = 180;
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
```

How to save the image and see if it the rotation is working?

Comment: Use `imagejpeg`. See https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: With the above, without `imagejpeg`, you do not actually save the generated image so the operations probably succeeded but changes are not stored.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save the rotation of an image on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073623/how-to-save-the-rotation-of-an-image-on-server)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate image and save the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259881/how-to-rotate-image-and-save-the-image)

Answer (score 0):

So remove:

```
// header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

and add:

```
imagejpeg($rotate, 'rotated-image-name.jpg', 80);
```

Working code:

```
$filename = 'pexels-philip-justin-mamelic-2872667.jpg';
$degrees = 180;
// header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);
imagejpeg($rotate, 'rotated-image-name.jpg', 80);
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using any [image Processing and Generation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php) libraries like Imagick/ GD

**Example with [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)**

You have to use [imagerotate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) function in this cause

Code sample to rotate an image to 180 degree using GD.

```
$sourceImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('test-design-image.jpg');
$rotateImage = imagerotate($source, 180, 0);
$saveImage = imagejpeg($rotate, 'test-design-rotated.jpg');
imagedestroy($sourceImage);
imagedestroy($rotateImage);
```

You can use [Imagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) library also if this library is available with your php.

**Example with** [Imagick::rotateImage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.rotateimage.php)

```
$sourceImage = new Imagick('test-design-image.jpg');
$sourceImage->rotateImage(new \ImagickPixel(), 180);


$sourceImage->writeImage ("test-design-rotated.jpg"); // if it fails, use the 
following method
file_put_contents ("test-design-rotated.jpg", $sourceImage);
```

Imagick may not installed by default with most php and wampp/lampp/xampp installations. You can check with phpinfo() to verify that Imagick is installed or not.